# Ethereum Geth Node Syncing Issues

Tags: go-ethereum, ethernodes

I am currently synchronizing an Ethereum geth full node and am noticing some oddities in my log after roughly 4 days.

I followed the below tutorial, using the same version etc. : https://kauri.io/#communities/Ethereum%20Node%20Runners/running-an-ethereum-full-node-on-a-raspberrypi-4-/

[image: geth logs]

Additionally inside of the `geth --dev console`;
`web3.eth.syncing` returns false

Based on the other geth node error threads I have read that getting false indicates that you have synced up to the current block but based on https://ethstats.net/ I still have roughly 3mil blocks to go...

Is it just part of the process or do I need to start from scratch?

Any feedback and help is appreciated

UPDATE - the change in version(1.10.3) got the node back to syncing
*note that out-of-memory error came up later; would recommend using version 1.10.2(stable)as of 4/30/21 just in case that played a roll*

-arelius

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it will say false until you are synced.

Do you have the 8GB RAM version of the Pi? It helps to give geth 2GB at least.

Are you on the latest geth version?

Is your computer clock syncing correctly? Milliseconds matter.

Is there something interfering with your inbound network, like a firewall?

Has your ISP throttled you for extreme bandwidth usage?

Are you writing to an SSD? HDDs aren't fast enough to maintain time sync with peers. You can get maddeningly close to sync but unable to actually sync.

Comment: Thanks for the response; yes I have 8GB ram, I am on 1.9.6 geth(I figured going with a stable version would work- will updating it now require a fresh db restart?), I think its possible that the clock is off, yes I have a firewall-would I have to permanently disconnect it for the node? and yes I am using an SSD

Comment: A geth restart might help - it will cause your node to re-establish connections with a fresh set of peers. If it can't - that's a clue. Your router/wifi probably already supports UPnP so geth should be able to open the port/s it needs automatically. But if something changed and peers can't talk to you then that might explain it too. Apart from that I'm out of ideas - waiting for my own node to sync too.

Comment: PS My sync failed. I searched and found out you have to upgrade to geth 1.10.2 in order to get beyond the Berlin hard fork.

Comment: ohh okay, I will give that a shot then. I messed with the ideas you mentioned and adjusted cache numbers but I wasn't getting any better results-just different errors. Thanks !

Comment: UPDATE - the change in version(1.10.3) got the node back to syncing so yay! ... I eventually hit a wall due to an out of memory error so I have some exploring to do with my cache but that much appears to be a more straightforward issue.